# What is the difference between {} 1>&2 and () 1>&2 in an output-captured function in bash

Tags: bash, function, io-redirection

1. with `{}` - execute while loop in the **current shell**

   ```
   function f {
       {
           while : ; do echo -n a; done  &
       } 1>&2
   }

   a=$( f ); echo "returned"
   ```

   -> `f()` will *never* return!!!
2. `()` execute while loop in a **subshell**

   ```
   function f {
       (
           while : ; do echo -n a; done  &
       ) 1>&2
   }

   a=$( f ); echo "returned"
   ```

   -> `f()` *will* return!!!

**Why?** will one of them return, but not the other? I don't get it...

---

### My analysis:

The `while` loop will be forked and start its own background process due to the ending `&` on the `while`-loop line. This background process inherits the current open fd list.

As far as I understand, since the `while` loop is encapsulated, it inherits the encapsulation's fd list. This is how

```
{ echo log; echo err 1>&2; } 1>l_file 2>e_file
```

works as expected, `l_file` will contain "log", `e_file` will contain "err".

So in either the case of `{} 1>&2` or `() 1>&2`, bash is informed that it should expect no stdout to capture.

Why is it blocking on the `{} 2>&1` case?

- some evaluation order mystery?
- maybe closing the stdout explicitly would help? I don't know the syntax, though, maybe `{} 1>&- 1>&2` would help?

---

GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

---

### EDIT

Based on the answers so far, I did some more analysis:

**11)** `{}`

```
function f {
    {
        while : ; do echo -n a; done  &
        echo "after loop"
    } 1>&2
    echo "end of function"
}

a=$( f ); echo "returned"
```

-> `after loop` is displayed

**12)** `()`

```
function f {
    (
        while : ; do echo -n a; done  &
        echo "after loop"
    ) 1>&2
    echo "end of function"
}

a=$( f ); echo "returned"
```

-> `after loop` is displayed

-> `returned` is displayed

Comment: As an aside, consider avoiding the `function` keyword -- it makes your code incompatible with POSIX sh, but (unlike more useful bashisms) offers no benefits over the standardized `f() { ...; }` function declaration syntax.

Comment: BTW, the shell could very well change this behavior in the future, closing such temporary FDs when forking off a subshell that won't/can't exit the block scope such as to make the restore in question necessary. I wouldn't advise counting on it behaving either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A command substitution doesn't return until the FIFO it opens as output is closed.

When you redirect a subshell, that subshell doesn't hold a file descriptor pointing to the original FD; it doesn't have any need to, since the redirection will be implicitly ended by that subshell's termination.

When you redirect a block, **the block needs to retain a copy of the original descriptor to restore on exit**. Consequently, there will be an automatically-assigned file descriptor storing a copy of the original (pre-redirection) stdout, and the existence of this FD prevents the FIFO from having the write end closed.

---

Observe the difference:

```
f() {
  ls -l "/proc/$BASHPID/fd"
}

out1=$( ( f; ) 2>&1; )
out2=$( { f; } 2>&1; )
```

In the above, `out1` may (with irrelevant fields stripped) look like:

```
0 -> /dev/pts/0
1 -> pipe:[1146313]
2 -> pipe:[1146313]
255 -> /dev/pts/0
```

...whereas `out2` may under similar conditions look like:

```
0 -> /dev/pts/0
1 -> pipe:[1146327]
10 -> /dev/pts/0
2 -> pipe:[1146327]
255 -> /dev/pts/0
```

Note the additional FD 10, storing a backup to be restored.

Comment: so because `out2` still holds a the original fd, the calling function can't return? Can you share a resource to read about this subject? what actually happens when both pipes are closed? Thanks

Comment: @Vinny, the function can return, but the command substitution it's invoked from can't exit (because not all copies of the write end of the FIFO are closed, the read end never reaches EOF condition). The `echo "end of function"` in the OP's test only fails to be visible to the calling user because it's written to stdout, not stderr.